# Getting multiple outputs of a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I use a function which may return outputs more than 3 or 4 which makes it hard to assign those numbers / matrices to user defined variables one by one. Here is the example:

```
k = fix(log2(length(s)))
[c,l] = wavedec(s,k,'db1');
[cd1,cd2,cd3, ... , cdk] = detcoef(c,l,1:k);
```

k is 22 in this example. How can I get those outputs by not writing all cd's from 1 to 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create those dynamic variables. Just use:

```
D = detcoef(c,l,1:k);
```

This will create a cell array having the same contents as of `cd1`, `cd2`, ..., `cdk` at its 1st, 2nd, ..., kth index respectively. Access them using `D{1}`, `D{2}`,..., `D{k}` respectively.